# Which is the right expression between x86_64 and x86_x64?

Tags: naming

I can find the word x86_64 and x86_x64 on many of some software products. Which is the right or more appropriate expression between them?

In my opinion, x86_64 is the right one, as "x86 is a CPU model name. The character x is shortened by 80, 801, 802, 803 and subsequent models by Intel and all other Intel or AMD defined CISC. 64 is a bit length. x86 with 64bit capability can be called x86-64bit which is shorten to x86-64 or even x64." x86 already stands for CPU model type, thus adding x again is a sort of duplication.

My question looks like it is trivial, but it matters when I build a multi-platform library where folder name might give confliction to the users.

Comment: AMD calls their version AMD64. Intel calls their version Intel 64. It appears that the industry has arrived at a consensus name `x86-64` for the common portion of the two architectures. (Many projects chose their names before the industry consensus emerged, which is why the names tend to be inconsistent.)